# Null check operator used on a null value when fetching data from streambuilder

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

i uploaded some data in my cloud firestore and i am trying to use the StreamBilder to fetch those data.In order to do this i created a model for the data i uploaded to the cloud firestore and tried to get the data but when i run the program, it gives me the 'Null check operator used on a null value' error.
This is my data on firestore[image]

This is the model i created for the data

```
class VendorUserModels{
  final bool? approved;
  final String? businessName;
  final String? cityValue;
  final String? countryValue;
  final String? email;
  final String? phoneNo;
  final String? stateValue;
  final String? storeImage;
  final String? taxNumber;
  final String? taxValue;

  VendorUserModels(
      {
        required this.approved,
        required this.businessName,
        required this.cityValue,
        required this.countryValue,
        required this.email,
        required this.phoneNo,
        required this.stateValue,
        required this.storeImage,
        required this.taxNumber,
        required this.taxValue
      }
      );
  VendorUserModels.fromJson(Map<String, Object?> json):
        this(
        approved: json['approved']! as bool,
        businessName: json['businessName']! as String,
        cityValue: json['cityValue']! as String,
        countryValue: json['countryValue']! as String,
        email: json['email']! as String,
        phoneNo: json['phoneNo']! as String,
        stateValue: json['stateValue']! as String,
        storeImage: json['storeImage']! as String,
        taxNumber: json['taxNumber']! as String,
        taxValue: json['taxValue'] as String,
      );
  Map<String, Object?>toJson(){
    return{
      'businessName': businessName,
      'email':email,
      'phone number': phoneNo,
      'country': countryValue,
      'state':stateValue,
      'city': cityValue,
      'tax options': taxValue,
      'tax number': taxNumber,
      'image': storeImage,
      'approved':approved
    };
  }
}
```

and this is the streambuilder i am using to fetch the data

```
class LandingScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const LandingScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    final CollectionReference _vendorsStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('vendors');
    return Scaffold(
      body:  StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
        stream: _vendorsStream.doc(_auth.currentUser!.uid).snapshots(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return const Text('Something went wrong');
          }

          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const Text("Loading");
          }
          VendorUserModels _vendorUserModel = VendorUserModels.fromJson(snapshot.data!.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>);
            return Text(_vendorUserModel.businessName.toString());


        }
        )
    );
  }
}
```

the error screenshot
[image]

Comment: can you add the error screenshot 
from that we can easily find out which key is getting null value

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to use null-assert and `as` prefix with non-nullabe, datatype are already nullable.

You can do

```dart
VendorUserModels.fromJson(Map<String, Object?> json):
    this(
    approved: json['approved'] as bool?,
    businessName: json['businessName'] as String?,
    cityValue: json['cityValue'] as String?,
    countryValue: json['countryValue'] as String?,
    email: json['email'] as String?,
    phoneNo: json['phoneNo'] as String?,
    stateValue: json['stateValue'] as String?,
    storeImage: json['storeImage'] as String?,
    taxNumber: json['taxNumber'] as String?,
    taxValue: json['taxValue'] as String?,
  );
```

Comment: Glad to help, you can find more about [null-safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety)